# ¿Como mido el perímetro en distancia real del contorno de una imagen?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

A ver si me pueden ayudar con esto.

Estoy trabajando con las librerías OpenCV y Numpy en Python. Obtengo todo el contorno de un lago y lo que necesito es saber cuanto mide (perímetro) en distancia real (metros, kilómetros).

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda que me puedan brindar para aclarar mi pregunta.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Bienvenido  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Además de lo que comenta Patricico, referido a la pregunta en si, para poder estimar distancias reales en la imagen es necesario tener información extra, por ejemplo conocer las medidas de otro objeto en la misma (y calcular los pixeles por metro), conociendo ciertos parámetros de la cámara y la distancia de la misma al objeto fotografiado, que te den la escala directamente, etc ¿Tienes algo de esto? Si solo tienes una imagen sin nada más es complicado.... Se pueden hacer estimaciones si reconocemos otros objetos en la imagen de medidas más u menos std (una carretera, automóvil...  p.e).

Comment: @FJSevilla Hola, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Te comento, lo que quiero hacer es medir el perimetro del lago, la distancia de la cámara al lago es algo que ya conozco, tambien conozco el modelo de la cámara exacto por lo que puedo obtener todas sus especificaciones técnicas así como también puedo. Gracias a ambos!.